# Plot 3D Grid Data as Heat Map using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, visualization, heatmap

Assume we have a 5x4x3 3D grid, where each cell has a value:

```
0.5523    0.0495    0.1465    0.5386
0.6299    0.4896    0.1891    0.6952
0.0320    0.1925    0.0427    0.4991
0.6147    0.1231    0.6352    0.5358
0.3624    0.2055    0.2819    0.4452

0.1239    0.2085    0.9479    0.6210
0.4904    0.5650    0.0821    0.5737
0.8530    0.6403    0.1057    0.0521
0.8739    0.4170    0.1420    0.9312
0.2703    0.2060    0.1665    0.7287

0.7378    0.8589    0.1339    0.3329
0.0634    0.7856    0.0309    0.4671
0.8604    0.5134    0.9391    0.6482
0.9344    0.1776    0.3013    0.0252
0.9844    0.3986    0.2955    0.8422
```

How can I achieve a plot in gnuplot that is similar to this plot achieved in matlab using `patch`? Note that the grid cells has an alpha value of 0.8.
[image]

Comment: No, you cannot get such plot with gnuplot in a sane way.